# Create a Git branch that cannot be merged back into master

Tags: git, merge

I want to create a branch in git that cannot be merged back into master but master can be merged into it.  It needs to be a "separate" product but it will be 99% the same with some small tweaks.  So new features in master need to be merged into the new feature branch but the new feature branch should *never* be able to merge back into master.

Comment: This sounds like a better fit for a clone of your repository...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could fork

```
git init special-product
cd special-product
git remote add standard-product <URL>
git pull standard-product master
git remote rm stardard-product
```

now you have it local in another repo.
you may need to create a new remote in an analog way to your standard-product repo

Comment: Yea, I am thinking I just need to create a completely new repository and then just merge in from the separate origin.  The issue is if the code ever merged back into the standard-product repo...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is a good idea to put the slightly modified application into a separate branch. If both applications are 99% the same I would encourage you to make the code more flexible. You could create a config file and let the application behaving differently based on that config file.

Comment: I wish it was that easy but legally we can't just have a software switch, it has to be incapable of adding the other feature...